# ignore end of line difference while applying patch

Tags: svn, patch

Is it possible to ignore EOL differences while applying patch?

(The situation happens when patch is created in a windows machine but applied in linux.)

Thanks.

Comment: Visting this post after a long time. Dont remember how i exactly resolved this situation. But I think I applied dos2unix to the Linux files after patching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get patch to ignore carriage returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754972/how-do-i-get-patch-to-ignore-carriage-returns)